# Is it possible to return Date math with elastic?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I find myself using relative times to define ranges such as now-3d to now. Elastic converts that to usable timestamps and returns values in that range, but it doesnt return the date itself. Is it possible for elastic to give you the date range?

What I had in mind was essentially:

```
GET url/time_math
{
    "range":
    {
        "from": "now-1w/w",
        "to": "now/w"
    }
}
```

output:

```
{
    "range": 
    {
        "from": "2022-03-13T00:00:00",
        "to": "2022-03-19T23:59:59"
    }
}
```

I am using python / python elastic library to do these queries. If I can do it in the scripting lang, would work too.

Elastic is able to determine these timestamps for relative dates really well, can be difficult to compute from api/front end at times to set for custom graphs.

Comment: It's always best to show concrete examples of what you're doing and what you're expecting. Code is worth a 1000 words ;-)

Comment: Made an edit, let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: any thoughts on this @Val ?